# How to re-write code to assign anonymous type to listbox

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone please help me re-write the following code? I need to have both the groupId and groupName to set the data fields of my listbox.

```
if (categoryId == null)
                {
                    var groups = usersData.Where(g => g.groupName != null).Select(g => new { groupId = g.groupId, groupName = g.groupName }).Distinct();                                        
                }
                else
                {
                    var groups = usersData.Where(g => g.categoryId == Convert.ToInt32(categoryId)).Select(g => new { groupId = g.groupId, groupName = g.groupName }).Distinct();         
                    
                }

                lstGroups.DataValueField = "groupId";
                lstGroups.DataTextField = "groupName";
                lstGroups.DataSource = groups; 
                lstGroups.DataBind();
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Why do you need to rewrite it?

Comment: Because when I compile I get "The name 'groups' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: You have `groups` variable declared and initialized inside `if` and `else` block. You can not access them outside of them. That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: Yes, understand, so how can this be re-written using a conditional?

Answer (score 2):

You have the `group` variable created inside the `if` and `else` blocks. You can not access that variable outside of those blocks. That's why you are getting this error.

The solution is to declare the variable `groups` before the `if` block.

Inside `if` and `else` you are creating a list of dynamically created objects which has `groupId` and `groupName` properties. You can not create a list of such unknown types.

**Solution 1**

So instead of dynamic typed objects, you can use `Tuple<,>` type.

The following code will create a list of type `Tuple<int, string>`. And create a collection using `Select`.

```
var groups = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

if (categoryId == null)
{
    groups = usersData
        .Where(g => g.groupName != null)
        .Select(g => new Tuple<int, string>(g.groupId, g.groupName))
        .Distinct();                                        
}
else
{
    groups = usersData
        .Where(g => g.categoryId == Convert.ToInt32(categoryId))
        .Select(g => new Tuple<int, string>(g.groupId, g.groupName))
        .Distinct();
}
```

Tuples have properties `Item1` and `Item2`, you can use them as `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` as following.

```
lstGroups.DataValueField = "Item1";
lstGroups.DataTextField = "Item2";
lstGroups.DataSource = groups.ToList(); 
lstGroups.DataBind();
```

**Solution 2**

You can also use named value tuples which gives you more control over how the Tuple values can be accessed.

```
var groups = new List<(int groupId, string groupName)>();
```

The above list is of tuple values. You can access the values of individual tuples by using names `groupId` and `groupName`.

```
if (categoryId == null)
{
    groups = usersData
        .Where(g => g.groupName != null)
        .Select(g => (g.groupId, g.groupName))
        .Distinct();                                        
}
else
{
    groups = usersData
        .Where(g => g.categoryId == Convert.ToInt32(categoryId))
        .Select(g => (g.groupId, g.groupName))
        .Distinct();
}
```

Now you can use `groupId` and `groupName` names of values of tuples to assigned to `DataValueField` and `DataTextField`.

```
lstGroups.DataValueField = "groupId";
lstGroups.DataTextField = "groupName";
lstGroups.DataSource = groups.ToList(); 
lstGroups.DataBind();
```

Comment: "you are creating a list of dynamically created objects [...] You can not create a list of such unknown types." I don't understand that one. The datatype of `usersData` hasn't been stated, but I'd _hope_ it would be a collection of a custom class that contains the groupId and groupName properties.

Comment: `Select(g => new { groupId = g.groupId, groupName = g.groupName })` creates a dynamic object of no predefined type. I wanted to suggest to use List of `usersData`, but OP uses `Distict` for some reason and also to bind data to lstBox other data or `userData` is required.

Comment: I'm not sure why the previous answer was deleted, but that is what actually worked.